# how to remotely install/unistall android application from web page

Tags: php, android

I am unable to find a probable solution of how to remotely install any application using web page ?

Like pressing a button on webpage installs application on phone.

Please guide me for this requirement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Host your APK file on your server, create a link to it on your web page, that's all. Navigate to the page on the device and click the link, it will offer to install the app.

You need to have the option `Settings > Security > Unknown sources` activated on the device for it to work.